# Visual Studio 2019 does not recognise .Net 5 installation

Tags: visual-studio

I recently upgraded my Visual Studio to version 16.8.4. This seems to have also installed .Net 5 (I don't remember it asking me if I wanted that). However, a project from the earlier installation was using .Net 4.7.1 which seems to have been uninstalled.

But when I try to update that project's properties I can't find any valid version of .Net at all - just a load of old ones. See the attached screenshot. I've tried rebooting but that didn't help.
Any ideas how to get VS to acknowledge the existence of .Net v 5?

[image: List of available targets]

Comment: .Net versions are backward-compatible, so version 4.7.2 should work.

Comment: .Net 5.0 is not a regular Framework. Instead it is a .Net Core release which has a slightly different API, hence it is not compatible to the releases your list shows.

Comment: The problem is your project originally targetted .NET Framework 4.8 but you want to target .NET 5, you have to port your project, in order to target .NET (Core) 5

Comment: .NET 5.0 is not an upgrade to .NET Framework 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

> I recently upgraded my Visual Studio to version 16.8.4. This seems to have also installed .Net 5 (I don't remember it asking me if I wanted that). However, a project from the earlier installation was using .Net 4.7.1 which seems to have been uninstalled.

When you updated Visual Studio it most likely updated your .NET Framework installation to 4.7.2 since 4.7.1 isn't supported.  However, you can still download the developer pack, which includes the necessary targeting profile for .NET Framework 4.7.1

Source: [Install the .NET Framework for developers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers#:%7E:text=A%20targeting%20pack%20lets%20your%20app%20target%20a,accompanying%20SDK%20along%20with%20its%20corresponding%20targeting%20pack.)

> But when I try to update that project's properties I can't find any valid version of .Net at all - just a load of old ones. See the attached screenshot. I've tried rebooting but that didn't help. Any ideas on how to get VS to acknowledge the existence of .Net v 5?

The simplest process would be to port your .NET Framework project to a .NET Framework Core project.  .NET Framework 5 is the current version of the .NET Framework Core.  In reality, the entire problem is due to your project file, so that is more than likely the only thing that has to change.

[Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

Comment: I cannot provide specific steps to port the author's project, that is something that they will have to figure out, or ask on the proper Stack Exchange community website.  I can only provide the reason .NET 5.0 is not listed as an applicable .NET Framework to target.

Comment: When I updated VS it seems to have installed .Net 5.0 (at least, the directory was created at the same time).   Also, I thought this was the proper Stack Exchange community. If not, which should I use - there doesn't seem to be one for Visual Studio?

Comment: @Peter - I was talking about the process to port your project to .NET 5.  That process is out of scope here at Super User since that is entirely based on your project and would be an extremely broad concept.  It would also be out of scope at Stack Overflow unless you indicated what specific code you were having trouble with.  **I have answered your question, you have to port your project to .NET Core, that is the reason you cannot target .NET 5**

Comment: Sorry if I offended you. I'll look at those links. It's been several months since I last used VS and I hadn't realised the ramifications of the forced move to ,NET 5.This was not signalled by Microsoft when I did the update, or I might have thought twice about it. It's quite a lot of work just to continue working on a simple project.  It seems that I can still debug the project with a bit of tweaking thanks to help from the MS Q&A forum.

Comment: You have not offended me but your comments are extremely difficult to understand.  I spent a reasonable amount of time in my answer to explicitly answer your question.

Comment: I'm not asking for steps to port the project - your links seem to give me enough info for that. I am more than slightly annoyed that a minor upgrade to VS seemed to result in a complete rejig of a simple (Windows form app with no dependencies) project without any prior warning. Not anyone here's fault...

Comment: Have you ported the project? I provided links to that process.

Comment: I was given this solution in the Microsoft Q&A forum, and it works, so I haven't tried porting yet. I might in the future, but have more pressing concerns at the moment. Again, thanks for your help and concern. You can try to use this method:

    Run cmd in administrator mode

    Type this command: regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\msdia140.dll"